# How do I introduce parallelism in current input pipeline in Tensoflow

Tags: tensorflow

I have created a model which takes batches of **X, Y** through the *feed_dict* when I run the session. Where **X and Y are numpy arrays**.

The batch function is a ***data-iterator*** which yields a batch everytime it is called. So, a new batch of **X** and **Y** yields and is fed to the model till the counter reaches total no. of batches.

How can I utilize ***tf.train.batch*** for this? I am aware it uses a **Queue** and can be used for multi-threaded training. I need solutions to optimize my input pipeline and how to use ***tf.train.batch***.